# Passing default-target to systemd with systemctl switch-root

Tags: linux, systemd

`systemd` provides the possibility to set the default target via:

- kernel parameter `systemd.unit=`
- argument `--unit=UNIT`
- or by setting a link, e.g. `/usr/lib/systemd/system/default.target`, in the rootfs.

`systemd` can be used in initramfs, switching over to the rootfs by isolating with initrd-switch-root.target [(link)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/bootup.html). The kernel provides for this case two parameters (systemd.unit=, rd.systemd.unit=), but I do not know how they work in that case.

Is it possible to set the default target for `systemd` after the rootfs-switch, within in the initramfs phase, while `systemd` is used in initramfs and rootfs? If yes how would I do that?

*Background:* I retrieve data in the initramfs phase via a socket-connection. Based on that data I want to tell `systemd` what target (runlevel) it shall go for directly after switching to the rootfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: `systemd` provides the argument --unit=UNIT (`systemd --help`), so calling:

```
exec switch_root /mnt/root /sbin/init --unit=${target}
```

meets my requirements.